# Full screen overlay in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a full screen program that overlays the status bar so that you can see it but cannot click on it (like the lock screen). When I run my program in Ice Cream Sandwich my app drops down below the status bar (allowing it to be touched). How can I get it to work again in ICS?

I use the following code:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams mOverLayParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only solution with replacing TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY. But in this way your window will not receive touch events.

Comment: I do not think I will get it to work (at least not without root). The only reason it worked in the first place was due to an exploit that has been fixed.

Comment: I used it in my app (Cool Tool). The problem with Navigation Bar in Jelly Bean. Seems nav bar have more high priority than SYSTEM_OVERLAY. But this solution works well with phone status bar even on JB

Answer (score 0):

Try the `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`.

Documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Example:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately that will completely remove the status bar. I want it to be visible but not touchable.